# Widget Stack not showing top levels

Tags: flutter, dart

I make the Stack widget as usual, but the InkWell widget doesn't appear on top of the blue Container. For the experiment, I put other widgets in its place and everything works. What did I do wrong? Here is the part of the code:

```
          Stack(
            children: [
            Container(height: 280, color: Colors.blue,),
            Row(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                Mainpage()));
                  }, 
                  splashColor: Colors.brown.withOpacity(0.5),
                  child: Ink(
                    height: 48,
                    width: 48,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image:
                        AssetImage('assets/dagger.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Here I made the container transparent and you can see that InkWell is there and is located under the container:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Wrap Stack with a Container or Sizedbox and give it a fixed height

Comment: There is nothing to screenshot here. Just a blue rectangle. But he reacts to pressing InkWell. It's just not visible under the container. Wrap Stack with a Container or Sizedbox - Tried. Does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `InkWell` to `Positioned` and set the position with the `Stack` and wrap your `InkWell` to a `Material` widget. This is for  making sure that `InkWell` has a parent that can handle the tap event:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(height: 280, color: Colors.blue,),
    Positioned(
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Mainpage()
              )
            );
          }, 
          splashColor: Colors.brown.withOpacity(0.5),
          child: Ink(
            height: 48,
            width: 48,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/dagger.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

happy coding...

Comment: Magic. But it doesn't work...

Comment: In my idea my old answer could help but without any screenshot or more detail it'll be hard my friend, but try my edited answer please.

Comment: Everything is working. Thank you! Now I will understand why it works like this

Answer (score 0):

Make your Inc widget in Material widget :

```
child: Material(
   child: Ink(
   height: 48,
   width: 48,
   decoration: const BoxDecoration(
     image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('assets/dagger.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
   ),
  )
),
```